# Given the estimator find wheter

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, estimation

X has an uniform distribution on interval $(0,\theta]$ where $\theta$ is a positive parameter
Given the estimator:
$$T(X_1,X2, \ldots, X_n)=\frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
Find whether this estimator is consistent (i am not certain whether it is a best english equivalent of what i mean). But in symbols i mean:

[image]

Generaly speaking i know it is satisfied by 
$R(\theta)=\frac{\theta^2}{3n}+0$ and the fact that this expression converges to zero. However i do not understand why and where does this answer comes from.

Comment: What is the distribution of $X_i$?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: What you've stated is that you want to know whether the estimator converges in probability to $\theta$

Comment: Could you elaborate on that i mean is my answer correct or not? Where AM i wrong?

Comment: Is there a typo in your answer $R(\theta)$, why is there a $0$ added in

Comment: I mean that is what i had as an answer IT is not typo something there should be equal to zero i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X_i$ are i.i.d.

1) You can simply use the WLLN and continuous mapping theorem to deduce that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \xrightarrow{p}EX = \frac{\theta}{2}$, hence $\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \xrightarrow{p} \theta$.

2) You can use the theorem that if  $\lim_{n\to \infty} MSE(\hat{\theta}_n) = 0$ then $\hat{\theta}_n$ converges in probability to $\theta$. In your case it is straightforward to show that 
$$
MSE(\hat{\theta}) = Var(\hat{\theta})+b^2(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{2^2}{n^2}nVar(X_i) = \frac{\theta^2}{3n}
$$ 
which is clearly goes to  $0$ as $n \to  \infty$.

(Note that $EX_i = \frac{\theta}{2}$ and $Var(X_i) = \frac{\theta^2}{12}$)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!